# how to use name space instead of hard coded url in django templales for pagination

Tags: python, django, pagination

i am newbie in django,i have django templates where i have added the following code for pagination.here you can see that i have apply **hard coded url** for pagination.but i don't want to use **hard coded url** ,i want to use **namespace** instead of the **hard coded url**.how can i do this.

Template:

```
<span class="page-links">
                        {% if page_obj.has_previous %}
                            {% if query_string %}
                                <a href="/dash/{{ point.id }}/full/combination/?page={{ page_obj.previous_page_number }}&{{ query_string }}">previous</a>
                            {% else %}
                                <a href="/dash/{{ point.id }}/full/combination/?page={{ page_obj.previous_page_number }}">previous</a>
                            {% endif %}
                        {% endif %}
</span>
```

my urls:

```
url(r'^(?P<chain_pk>[0-9]+)/full/combination/$',
    CombinationSearchList.as_view(), name='dash_combination_search_list'),
```

**Update**

my django version is 1.6

Comment: Have a look at https://docs.djangoproject.com/es/1.9/ref/templates/builtins/#url

Comment: @AnkitJaiswal i forgot to mention the django version.i am using 1.6.

Comment: I don't think there is any difference in these two versions for template url rendering.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<span class="page-links">
    {% if page_obj.has_previous %}
        {% if query_string %}
            <a href="{% url 'dash_combination_search_list' point.id %}?page={{ page_obj.previous_page_number }}&{{ query_string }}">previous</a>
        {% else %}
            <a href="{% url 'dash_combination_search_list' point.id %}?page={{ page_obj.previous_page_number }}">previous</a>
        {% endif %}
    {% endif %}
</span>
```

Please note that I have used `point.id` on the url to provide the value for the point.id in your hardcoded url. This can be any other variable, like `object.pk` or `object.id` or any other context variable. If this is not clear post again with the view code of the page and I can help.